# Use 1 out of 2 returned values as string

Tags: python

```
divmod(X, Y)
```

returns (A, B)

How would I turn *either* A or B into a string?

EDIT: to clarify, I'd like to use them 1 at a time :)

Comment: As indicated by the existence of two very different answers, you should clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
str(divmod(x, y)[0])
```

and

```
str(divmod(x, y)[1])
```

respectively?

You can also write

```
a, b = divmod(x, y)
str(a)
str(b)
```

(Of course you should do something with `str(a)` instead of simply creating it.)

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to randomly select one or the other:

```
import random
str(random.choice(divmod(X,Y)))
```